# How to add activation regularisation to tensorflow layer

Tags: tensorflow

Some model, like sparse autoencoder, require activation regularization 
But I can't find a API that regularize activation of a layer.

Is there some way to add a customized regularizer?
Or are layer activations tf.trainablevariables?

I'm aware of tensorflow can apply l2 regularisation on weight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to achieve exactly:

- [tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/apply_regularization) allows you to combine a regularizer and a set of tensors on which it should be applied.
- [tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/l2_regularizer) allows you to defines the scope on which the l2 should be applied.
- But in essence a regularizer is just something to be added to the cost function, so any function (tensor) which you add to the cost function can be considered as a regularizer and will be taken into account.